# How to Install Outlook 2013 side-by-side with Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

Microsoft has just released Office 2013, and I need to be able run both Outlook 2010 and **Outlook 2013** on the same machine in order to check the rendering of html emails.  (I don't need to run both versions *simultaneously*, though.

When the preview version of Office 2013 was released, there were some postings about how to do this with the preview version (e.g. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/8ee9542a-bbdf-4af0-8cd6-eb2fc46a2422), but it's not clear to me whether this works with the release version.  (For example, what is the ClicktoRun version of Outlook?)  I also saw another post which said that side-by-side installation of Outlook was not possible with the "packaged" version of Outlook, but was possible with the Office365 subscription version.

Any help would be much appreciated.  --Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Not possible, see the following from MS Help text on the install screen:

```
    Outlook: Some things to consider
Before you install Outlook, you must remove any earlier version of Outlook, because two versions of Outlook can’t be on the same computer. If you want to keep an earlier version of Outlook, you must choose on the Installation Options tab to not install Microsoft Outlook 2013.

If you choose not to install Outlook 2013, the version of Outlook you kept won’t use Microsoft Word as its email editor. You’ll use the Outlook email editor instead and not be able to use the features in the Word email editor.
```

**UPDATE DUE TO COMMENT:**

In your position I would pick myself up a copy of Virtual PC or VMware and load Windows w/ a Copy of the old or new Outlook on it, depending on which one you only needed for testing.

Comment: This turns out to be incorrect.  I installed 2013 using "Customize" instead of "Upgrade" and then told it to retain all old versions, but Outlook 2010 was removed anyway.  The other Office 2010 versions were retained, though.

Comment: A chat with Microsoft technical support confirms that only one version of Outlook can be installed at a time.

Comment: Agreed that virtual machine is going to be the way to go.  Also, I had another chat with Microsoft Answers and confirmed that Office 365, though it uses some Click-to-Run technologies, does not virtualize the installation, so it is not a solution here.  (I had seen some comments that Click-to-Run versions of Office 2010 might be a solution, but those are no longer available.)

Comment: Can it be installed to different User Profiles under Windows?